# how to show image on top of bar chart in google chart?

Tags: charts, google-visualization

Currently we are in process of switching from Highcharts to Google Charts.
Using Highcharts we have a chart like

> [image]

where we have arrow image(downward red in current image) based on difference between actual and average value. i tried to achieve this using google charts but not getting anywhere. Till now I could only show HTML using the annotationText property.
Is this task possible using google chart? Is there any work around ?

Answer (score 0):

Here, I have provided only a suggestion of how you can have something appended to a column, and you can apply this to have your arrow appended to the bars.

You can use an **annotation** to the bars. The following example shows hoe you can annotate a simple text to the bar .

In this data table, we define a new column with { role: 'annotation' } to hold the bar labels:

```
   var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
     ['Element', 'Density', { role: 'style' }, { role: 'annotation' } ],
     ['Copper', 8.94, '#b87333', 'Cu' ],
     ['Silver', 10.49, 'silver', 'Ag' ],
     ['Gold', 19.30, 'gold', 'Au' ],
     ['Platinum', 21.45, 'color: #e5e4e2', 'Pt' ]
  ]);
```

Likewise, you can format the annotation to appear differently like the **red downward arrow** you wish to append by defining a formatter and wrapping it in a function like this:

```
function getValueAt(column, dataTable, row) 
{
    return dataTable.getFormattedValue(row, column);
}
```

For further info in this regard, you can refer [this](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart).

Comment: is there any fiddle available for this?

Comment: Not in the exact context of your question but you can check out some very similar examples provided in the link that I've specified in the answer itself